# Gensim word2vec WMD similarity dictionary

Tags: python, nlp, cpu-word, gensim, word2vec

I'm using word2vec on a 1 million abstracts dataset (2 billion words). To find most similar documents, I use the `gensim.similarities.WmdSimilarity` class. When trying to retrieve the best match using `wmd_similarity_index[query]`, the calculation spends most of its time building a dictionary. Here is a piece of log:

```
2017-08-25 09:45:39,441 : INFO : built Dictionary(127 unique tokens: ['empirical', 'model', 'estimating', 'vertical', 'concentration']...) from 2 documents (total 175 corpus positions)                                                        
2017-08-25 09:45:39,445 : INFO : adding document #0 to Dictionary(0 unique tokens: [])
```

What does this part ? Is it dependent on the query ? Is there a way to do these calculations once for all ?

**EDIT:** training and scoring phases in my code:

Training and saving to disk:

```
w2v_size = 300
word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(texts, size=w2v_size, window=9, min_count=5, workers=1, sg=1, hs=1, iter=20) # sg=1 means skip gram is used 
word2vec.save(utils.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_WORD2VEC)
corpus_w2v_wmd_index = gensim.similarities.WmdSimilarity(texts, word2vec.wv)
corpus_w2v_wmd_index.save(utils.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_CORPUS_WORD2VEC_WMD_INDEX)
```

Loading and scoring:

```
w2v = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(utils.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_WORD2VEC)
words = [t for t in proc_text if t in w2v.wv]
corpus_w2v_wmd_index = gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity.load(utils.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_CORPUS_WORD2VEC_WMD_INDEX)
scores_w2v = np.array(corpus_w2v_wmd_index[words])
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant part of your code ?

Comment: @Cedias it's done, training and scoring stages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Word Mover's Distance" calculation is relatively expensive – for each pairwise document comparison, it searches for an optimal 'shifting' of semantic positions, and that shifting is itself dependent on the pairwise simple-distances between all words of each compared document.

That is, it involves far more calculation than a simple cosine-distance between two high-dimensional vectors, and it involves more calculation the longer the two documents are.

There isn't much that could be pre-calculated, from the `texts` corpus, until the query's words are known. (Each pairwise calculation depends on the query's words, and their simple-distances to each corpus document's words.)

That said, there are some optimizations the gensim `WmdSimilarity` class doesn't yet do.

The original WMD paper described a quicker calculation that could help eliminate corpus texts that couldn't possibly be in the top-N most-WMD-similar results. Theoretically, the gensim `WmdSimilarity` could also implement this optimization, and give quicker results, at least when initializing the `WmdSimilarity` with the `num_best` parameter. (Without it, every query returns all WMD-similarity-scores, so this optimization wouldn't help.)

Also, for now the `WmdSimilarity` class just calls `KeyedVectors.wmdistance(doc1, doc2)` for every query-to-corpus-document pair, as raw texts. Thus the pairwise simple-distances from all `doc1` words to `doc2` words will be recalculated each time, even if many pairs repeat across the corpus. (That is, if 'apple' is in the query and 'orange' is in every corpus doc, it will still calculate the 'apple'-to-'orange' distance repeatedly.)

So, some caching of interim values might help performance. For example, with a query of 1000 words, and a vocabulary of 100,000 words among all corpus documents, the `((1000 * 100,000) / 2)` 50 million pairwise word-distances could be precalculated once, using 200MB, then shared by all subsequent WMD-calculations. To add this optimization would require a cooperative refactoring of `WmdSimilarity.get_similarities()` and `KeyedVectors.wmdistance()`.

Finally, Word2Vec/Doc2Vec applications don't necessarily require or benefit much from stop-word removal or stemming. But because the expense of WMD calculation grows with document and vocabulary size, anything that shrinks effective document sizes could help performance. So various ways of discarding low-value words, or coalescing similar words, may be worth considering when using WMD on large document sets.

Comment: Thx, good answer. Then the "building dictionary" part logged is just the WMD performing a count on the words of doc1 and doc2 being scored ?

Comment: To get a good scoring speed, I first use vectors means cosine distance on the entire database, then select top N similar documents and perform n_cosinus on them then reduce to top M and finally perform WMD scoring. It's definitely hazardous but I actually get some good results...

Comment: I'm not sure where your log lines "built Dictionary" come from – I don't see matching logging the the `similiarities/docsim.py` (where `WmdSimiliarity` is defined) or `models/keyedvectors.py` (where `wmdistance()` is defined) source code. (Meanwhile, that code *does* have other INFO-level logging not shown in your output.) Are you sure those log-lines are coming from exactly the code shown? (If you need to know, can you add more output context, or change the logging formatter to include the source class/method?)

Comment: Using a cruder, faster first-pass (like cosine-distance on the mean-of-all-word-vectors), then just doing WMD on the top items from that pass,  is similar to the paper's optimization – glad it's working well for you. (I think they more rigorously show that their specific calcs set firm bounds on what the WMD distance can be. In that way they can be sure certain docs couldn't be in the top-N, before doing WMD on those docs.)

Comment: @debzsud do you mind sharing your complete code? I am using WMDSimilarity gensim and performance is terrible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @gojomo - "Theoretically, the gensim WmdSimilarity could also implement this optimization, and give quicker results, at least when initializing the WmdSimilarity with the num_best parameter. " Even with num_best set to 10 performance is horrible. Wish RWMD was not abandoned, but looks like it is pretty challenging task for someone to handle